# How to access class properties in Unit Test

Tags: swift

I have a class:

```
public class Foo {
    public var options = "bar"
    public func someMethod() {
        //...
    }
}
```

When I access this `options` property in a test, the property name cannot be resolved, but I can still access the property from an instance outside of a test.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you provide example of a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options` should be testable.  Make sure you have a `@testable import` at the top for your app target in the unit tests:

```
import XCTest
@testable import UnitTest

class UnitTestTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testFoo() {
        let foo = Foo()

        XCTAssert(foo.options == "bar")
    }
}
```

In my Xcode this test passes:

[image: xcode tests being run]

If you're still seeing an issue, try cleaning the build folder.

Comment: restart the xcode solved the issue. thanks for your tip!